# How to redirect after a successful DELETE request

Tags: rest, http, redirect, http-delete

I have an HTML form performing a DELETE request (method = POST & hidden X-HTTP-Method-Override = DELETE)

When the DELETE request is successful, how do I tell the browser to redirect to another page?
Is 303 + header location okay?

Currently, the browser doesn't display the empty response but keep the previous response (I guess because of the 204 status code).
If I add a location header (still 204 status code) it does not change the location.

With 303+location I have the desired behavior but I wonder if 303 is a valid status code after a successful DELETE.
What about 202 (Accepted) DELETE ?

Comment: That's a POST request, not a DELETE request.

Comment: @JulianReschke the API actually DELETE request but it's not possible in all major browser to do a DELETE request without javascript (it's only a <form> in a page here). So the api look for X-HTTP-Method-Override form param to override the http method

Comment: No browser supports DELETE in forms. It's not part of HTML. Anyway: a POST request is a POST request, no matter how many custom headers you attach to it.

Comment: @JulianReschke yes, maybe I shouldn't have mention this in the question. What I want to know was what was the correct status code of a successful DELETE. That I abused a form param to fake the http method was unrelated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

303 plus Location is the best choice. Don't worry about what a "successful DELETE" is or means, because you're using POST, which has a different set of semantics, and 303 is tailor-made for [redirecting POST requests](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.4):

> **10.3.4 303 See Other**
>
> The response to the request can be found under a different URI and SHOULD be retrieved using a GET method on that resource. This method exists primarily to allow the output of a POST-activated script to redirect the user agent to a selected resource. The new URI is not a substitute reference for the originally requested resource. The 303 response MUST NOT be cached, but the response to the second (redirected) request might be cacheable.

Comment: maybe I shouldn't have said I was using a POST request: i'm using a POST a request here only because i can't d DELETE request in an HTML form (without javascript) other client will be doing a DELETE request. a POST+X-HTTP-method-override=DELETE request is seen by the controller as DELETE request. anyway, I think I will stick to 303 and mark you response as the answer if nobody came up with a better solution :)

Comment: I pick HTTP DELETE, and while returning proper 204 to be REST agnostic I passed redirect URL in headers